# Extending a contrib module so that an extra field is submitted to the database

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm using the fivestar contributed module and added it to my pages. I also have a custom helper module which allows me to extend the fivestar module so that I can add a custom widget. I've don this using the it's API HOOK_fivestar_widgets(). The helper module also creates a new field called Page_URL

What I want to do next is somehow extend the fivestar_form_submit() so that when selecting a star the vote + page url is submitted to the database.

My drupal skills are a bit rusty so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react on a form submission, simply add another submit function to the form definition by changing the fivestar form via [hook_form_FORMID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). The whole form values will be passed to your function and you can react on whatever is set in there.